# How to have user information in the controller in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to store the user_id in posts table(for every new post). I was passing user_id from the form as hidden_field. what is alternative way to get the user_id from the controller itself.

**in controller**

```
def create
    @post =@topic.posts.new(post_params).save
end
```

**post model**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :topic, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :user
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users # to maintain read and unread status for the posts
  has_many :comments , dependent: :destroy
  has_many :ratings , dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  end
```

**form**

```
<%= form_for [@topic, @post],remote: true,html: { multipart: true} do |form| %>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :author %>
      <%= form.text_field :author, :value => current_user.email %>
    </div>

      <%= form.label :content %>
      <%= form.text_area :content, id: :post_content, autofocus: true %>

    <!--<%= form.hidden_field :user_id %>-->

<div class="field">
  <%=form.label :image%><br>
  <%=form.file_field :image %>
</div>

    <%= form.fields_for :tags do |a|%>
    <div class="field">

      <%= a.label :tag_name %>
      <%= a.text_area :tag_name %>
    </div>
    <% end %>
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label "select tag" %>
      <%= form.collection_select(:tag_ids, Tag.all, :id, :tag_name, {}, {:multiple => true, :size => 10, :prompt_text => "select tag"}) %>
    </div>


    <div class="submit">
      <%= form.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How are you keeping track of the current signed in user? Can you post form code?

Comment: How do you store users? Do you use `devise` gem?

Comment: @xeon131  I have added form code

Comment: @MikhailKatrin yes. I'm using devise gem

Comment: @Aarthi in your form you're using current_user.email, you can do the similar in your controller. try `@topic.posts.new(post_params.merge(user: current_user)).save`

Comment: Thank you. Can you please post that  in answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `current_user` in controller, as below,

```
def create
  @topic.posts.new(post_params).save
end

private

def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(...).merge(user: current_user)
end
```

or

```
def create
  @topic.posts.new(post_params.merge(user: current_user)).save
end
```